# Cannot send mail through SMTP from VB6 program

Tags: vb6, smtp, transport

I have a legacy VB6 codebase which I would like to extend to include support for sending mails through an external SMTP server (smtp.live.com).

I use CDO for sending the mail. My machine runs Windows 7.
Unfortunately I get a "The transport failed to connect to the server" error message when trying to send send the mail.
Below is the code.

**VB6**

```
Dim oNewMessage As CDO.Message
Dim iConf As New CDO.Configuration
Dim oFlds As ADODB.Fields
Dim strbody As String


On Error GoTo errSMPT
    iConf.Load cdoDefaults
    Set oFlds = iConf.Fields
    oFlds(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    oFlds(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.live.com"
    oFlds(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 587
    oFlds(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 30
    oFlds(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    oFlds(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    oFlds(cdoSendUserName) = "xxxxxx@hotmail.com"
    oFlds(cdoSendPassword) = "mypassword"
    oFlds.Update

    strbody = "Sample message " & Time

    Set oNewMessage = New CDO.Message
    Set oNewMessage.Configuration = iConf

    With oNewMessage
        .To = txtTo.Text
        .From = txtFrom.Text
        .Subject = "subject"
        .TextBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    Exit Sub

errSMPT:
    MsgBox Err.Description
```

I don't think that the problem is related to firewall or account security issues since the C# code below works without any problems.

**C#**

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtText.Text))
                {
                    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);

                    mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@hotmail.com", "mypassword");
                    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    mailClient.Send(message);
                    MessageBox.Show("Message successfully sent!!!");                    
                }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

//Peter

Comment: Do you know if the VB version is using ssl?

Comment: If this can be of any help, your code works fine for me when sending with a Gmail account (smtp.googlemail.com on TCP/465), just as with my own code that uses CDO. However, I've never been able to send an email through CDO with a Live/Hotmail/Outlook.com account (tried again this time, just in case, without success).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
oFlds(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
```

This should be an integer instead of a boolean.  When VB6 converts true to and int, the value is -1.  I suggest you change that line to:

```
oFlds(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = 1
```

Comment: That field is indeed `Boolean`

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same no matter whether I set it to True or to 1.